# Accessing Params In Template EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

In my router, I have

```
 this.route('tends', { path: '/tends' }, function() {
    this.route('user', { path: ':usern' });
  });
```

How do I access, the `:usern` value in my template?

For example, I have tried

`{{params.usern}}`

and

`{{usern}}`

Unfortunately, neither of these approaches work.

Note: My template is for a route such as `tends/usern_here_please` and I want the value of `usern_here_please`.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a route as you have, the parameters are passed to your `Route` `model` hook like this:

```
App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('user', params.usern);
  }
});
```

Normally, objects are retrieved by `id`, so you would use `{{id}}` in your template for the object's id string.

Comment: That assumes the model promise was fulfilled so this isn't a proper approach or answer since it won't work in all situations.

Comment: What part of the answer assumes the model promise was fulfilled?

Comment: this.store.find('user', params.usern);

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to pass the params back as the model.

```js
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default class TendsUserRoute extends Route {
  // path is /tends/:usern
  model(params) {
    // params is an Object with a key of "usern"
    return params
  }
}
```

And then in the template, `params` is now your model.

```
<p>What is the user number? {{ @model.usern }}</p>
```

P.S. this is based on Ember 4.x but should work in older Ember but I think `@model` would be `this.model` in older versiona.